# Setting NSMenuItem modifier in Swift 4 results in "Type of expression is ambiguous"

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to set the keyboard shortcut modifier of a NSMenuItem.

```
myMenuItem.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .shift | .command
```

But I'm getting an error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".

I wasn't able to find how to use this bit operator correctly in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the C-style bitwise or. In Swift it has been changed to an `OptionSet`:

```
myMenuItem.keyEquivalentModifierMask = [.shift, .command]
```